# Rethinkdb reads are insanely slow

Tags: python, pandas, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I am simply trying to read all selected fields from a RethinkDB table into memory to construct a pandas DataFrame from it.
The table is indexed by an integer primary key and the database runs only one a single machine.
The code to read the data is:

```
    res = []
    for doc in r.db(db_name).table(table).pluck(keys).run(conn):
        res.append(doc)
    return pd.DataFrame(res).set_index(pk).sort_index()
```

The table has only 150k documents, each document has roughly 250 values, 10 columns, one column is an array of 240 values.

The database seems to stall, nothing happens for minutes then a "burst" of reads happens.

What's wrong?

[image: db1]

[image: db2]

Comment: For other readers: We're currently investigating this issue at https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4036